# Aligning content in html table

Tags: html, css

I want to align content in html in but not able to do it. Also i want to align checkbox to right and align to second textbox

Here is my html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >Age</td>
            <td >
                <select  ></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >Date changed</td>
            <td>
                <input />
                <input />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="test">Name</td>
            <td>
                <input id="txt1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Space">
            <td class="test">Is OK</td>
            <td>
                <input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NK4H/7/)

Comment: What do you mean in `one line` ?

Comment: What stuff do you want to show in one line?

Comment: @Alek i changed the question. I didnt meant to say one line but meant to say align properly one below another

Comment: @sanjay i want to align all controls properly one below another

Comment: try like <div style='float:right'> in <td> tag, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your html to following:

**html**

```
<table style="position: relative; margin-left: 8px;">
<tbody>
    <tr class="Space">
        <td class="test">Age</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <select  ></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Space">
        <td class="test">Date changed</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input />
            <input />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Space">               
                <tr>
                    <td class="test">Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="txtExecuted" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="test" style="text-align: right">Is Ok
                        <input id="chkNotExecuted" type="checkbox" />                        
                    </td>                         
                </tr>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NK4H/11/)

Comment: The checkbox is too right and not aligned with second textbox

Comment: Is it possible to have same space between all rows? The space between Age and Date changed is different from Name

Comment: Also the checkbox is not perfectly aligned and thats what i was struggling too

Comment: Yes but checkbox is not aligned to right below the second textbox

Comment: Everything is perfect now except the checkbox is not right aligned perfectly below second textbox in the row above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56407/discussion-between-alek-and-happy).

Comment: Very strange cause i'm using `<b>`. Anyway try this http://jsfiddle.net/7NK4H/23/

Comment: Still checkbox not perfectly aligned. If you try to use ruler on extreme right side of second textbox in second row and then see below that checkbox doesnt end exactly where second textbox ends.did you got it?

Comment: Ignoring the checkbox stuff for the moment and accepting answer

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <table style="position: relative; margin-left: 8px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="Space">
            <td class="test">Age</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <select  ></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Space">
            <td class="test">Date changed</td>
            <td>
                <table style='width:100%;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <input />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <input />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Space">
            <td class="test">Name</td>
            <td>
                <table style='width:100%;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <input id="txtExecuted" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%;text-align:right;">
                            <span style='margin-top:2px;'> Is Ok <input id="chkNotExecuted" type="checkbox" /> </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The checkbox should be right aligned and below the second textbox

Comment: The checkbox is not perfectly aligned and thats what i was struggling too

Comment: @Happy what you want to achieve , do you have any sketch or design ?

Comment: The checkbox you can see that is not aligned perfect below second textbox in row above. It should be right aligned perfectly below that textbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56408/discussion-between-dhaval-panchal-and-happy).